# merge contents of two files into one file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, merge

I have two files which has following contents

File1

```
Line1file1
Line2file1
line3file1
line4file1
```

File2

```
Line1file2
Line2file2
line3file2
line4file2
```

I want to have these file's content merged to file3 as

File3

```
Line1file1
Line1file2
Line2file1
Line2file2
line3file1
line3file2
line4file1
line4file2
```

How do I merge the files consecutively from one file and another file in bash?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can always use [`paste`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/upaste.htm) command.

```
paste -d"\n" File1 File2 > File3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file1
Line1file1
Line2file1
line3file1
line4file1

$ cat file2
Line1file2
Line2file2
line3file2
line4file2

$ paste -d '\n' file1 file2 > file3

$ cat file3
Line1file1
Line1file2
Line2file1
Line2file2
line3file1
line3file2
line4file1
line4file2
```

Answer (score 2):

`paste` is the way to go for this, but this alternative can be a useful approach if you ever need to add extra conditions or don't want to end up with blank lines when one file has more lines than the other or anything else that makes it a more complicated problem:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{print FNR, NR, $0}' file1 file2 | sort -n | cut -f3-
Line1file1
Line1file2
Line2file1
Line2file2
line3file1
line3file2
line4file1
line4file2
```

Comment: What would be needed to get an output such as:
Line1file1 line3file1
Line1file2 line3file2
Line2file1 line4file1
Line2file2 line4file2

(side by side)

Comment: Please post a new, followup question, don't ask followup questions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux:

```
grep -En '.?' File1 File2 | sed -r 's/^[^:]+:([^:]+):(.*)$/\1 \2/g' \
    | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f2- > File3
```

If you're on OS X, use `-E` instead of `-r` for the `sed` command.  The idea is this:

1. Use `grep` to number the lines of each file.
2. Use `sed` to drop the file name and put the line number into a space-separated column.
3. Use `sort -n` to sort by the line number, which is stable and preserves file order.
4. Drop the line number with `cut` and redirect to the file.

**Edit:** Using `paste` is much simpler but will result in blank lines if one of your files is longer than the other, this method will only continue with lines from the longer file.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line1 && read -u 3 line2
do 
    printf "$line1\n" >> File3
    printf "$line2\n" >> File3
done < File1 3<File2
```

you can use file descriptors, to read from two files and print each line to the out file.

Comment: This only appends the files, he wants alternate lines from each file

Comment: It will also strip leading and trailing white space from each line and expand escape sequences and produce syntax errors and/or other undesirable behavior if the file contains printf formatting chars (e.g. `%s`) and will be painfully slow. It's just another example of why writing loops in shell is always the wrong approach when manipulating text.